# COPY TO excel Sheet in foxpro

Tags: visual-foxpro

Is their any command in Foxpro that convert the DBF into a particular excel sheet.
I have three DBF(dbf_1, dbf_2, dbf_3). My current program convert the file using **copy to "filename.xls" type fox2x** and then I will manually copy the consolidate all the sheet into one excel. For me, this method I using is alright but what if their are 20 or more dbf that I will consolidate. Is their any command in foxpro that convert the dbf's into one excel file. I already use the foxpro Automation but it is to slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't.

Also "copy to ... type fox2x". although better than many other type selections (such as csv and xls) should not be chosen when there are better ways.

You are saying automation is slow, but don't know if you are really finding automation slow, or if you have tried it in the ways that you shouldn't use to transfer data to Excel. The sample below, use one of the variations of my "vfp2excel" function and automation. It transfers sample Customer, Employee, Orders, OrdItems and Products data in 2.5 seconds on my machine. If you really meant it as slow then no dice, otherwise here is the sample:

```
 * These represent complex SQL as a sample
Select emp_id,First_Name,Last_Name,;
    Title,Notes ;
    from (_samples+'\data\employee') ;
    into Cursor crsEmployee ;
    readwrite
Replace All Notes With Chrtran(Notes,Chr(13)+Chr(10),Chr(10))

Select cust_id,company,contact,Title,country,postalcode ;
    from (_samples+'\data\customer') ;
    into Cursor crsCustomer ;
    nofilter

Select * ;
    from (_samples+'\data\orders') ;
    into Cursor crsOrders ;
    nofilter

Select * ;
    from (_samples+'\data\orditems') ;
    into Cursor crsOrderDetail ;
    nofilter

Select * ;
    from (_samples+'\data\products') ;
    into Cursor crsProducts ;
    nofilter

* Now we want to get these on 3 sheets
* Sheet1: Employees only
* Sheet2: Customers only
* Sheet3: Orders, ordItems, Products layed out horizontally

Local oExcel
oExcel = Createobject("Excel.Application")
With oExcel
    .DisplayAlerts = .F.
    .Workbooks.Add
    .Visible = .T.
    With .ActiveWorkBook
        For ix = 1 To 3 && We want 3 Sheets
            If .sheets.Count < m.ix
                .sheets.Add(,.sheets(.sheets.Count)) && Add new sheets
            Endif
        Endfor
        * Name the sheets
        .WorkSheets(1).Name = "Employees"
        .WorkSheets(2).Name = "Customers"
        .WorkSheets(3).Name = "Order, OrderDetail, Products" && max sheetname is 31 chars

        * Start sending data
        * First one has headers specified
        VFP2Excel('crsEmployee',    .WorkSheets(1).Range("A1"), ;
            "Id,First Name,Last Name,Employee Title,Comments about employee" ) && To sheet1, start at A1
        VFP2Excel('crsCustomer',    .WorkSheets(2).Range("A1") ) && To sheet2, start at A1
        VFP2Excel('crsOrders',      .WorkSheets(3).Range("A1") ) && To sheet3, start at A1
        * Need to know where to put next
        * Leave 2 columns empty - something like 'G1'
        lcRange = _GetChar(.WorkSheets(3).UsedRange.Columns.Count + 3) + '1'
        * To sheet3, start at next to previous
        VFP2Excel('crsOrderDetail', .WorkSheets(3).Range(m.lcRange) )

        lcRange = _GetChar(.WorkSheets(3).UsedRange.Columns.Count + 3) + '1'
        * To sheet3, start at next to previous
        VFP2Excel('crsProducts',    .WorkSheets(3).Range(m.lcRange) )

        #Define xlJustify                                         -4130
        #Define xlTop                                             -4160

        * I just happen to know notes in at column 5 from SQL
        * No need to query from excel to keep code simple
        * Lets format that column specially instead of leaving
        * at the mercy of Excel's autofitting
        .WorkSheets(1).UsedRange.VerticalAlignment = xlTop && set all to top
        With .WorkSheets(1).Columns(5)
            .ColumnWidth = 80 && 80 chars width
            .WrapText = .T.
            *      .HorizontalAlignment = xlJustify && doesn't work good always
        Endwith

        * Finally some cosmetic stuff
        For ix=1 To 3
            With .WorkSheets(m.ix)
                .Columns.AutoFit
                .Rows.AutoFit
            Endwith
        Endfor

        .WorkSheets(1).Activate
    Endwith
Endwith


* Author: Cetin Basoz
* This is based on earlier VFP2Excel function codes
* that has been published on the internet, at various sites
* since 2001. Not to be messed with others' code who named the same but has
* nothing to do with the approaches taken here (unless copy & pasted and claimed
* to be their own work, < s > that happens).
Procedure VFP2Excel(tcCursorName, toRange, tcHeaders, tnPrefferredWidthForMemo)
    * tcCursorName
    * toRange
    * tcHeaders: Optional. Defaults to field headers
    * tnPrefferredWidthForMemo: Optional. Default 80
    * Function VFP2Excel
    tcCursorName = Evl(m.tcCursorName,Alias())
    tnPrefferredWidthForMemo = Evl(m.tnPrefferredWidthForMemo,80)
    Local loConn As AdoDB.Connection, loRS As AdoDB.Recordset,;
        lcTemp,lcTempDb, oExcel,ix, lcFieldName, lcHeaders

    lnSelect = Select()
    lcTemp   = Forcepath(Sys(2015)+'.dbf',Sys(2023))
    lcTempDb = Forcepath(Sys(2015)+'.dbc',Sys(2023))

    Create Database (m.lcTempDb)
    Select * From (m.tcCursorName) Into Table (m.lcTemp) Database (m.lcTempDb)

    Local Array aMemo[1]
    Local nMemoCount
    nMemoCount = 0
    lcHeaders = ''
    For ix = 1 To Fcount()
        lcFieldName = Field(m.ix)
        If Type(Field(m.ix))='M'
            nMemoCount = m.nMemoCount + 1
            Dimension aMemo[m.nMemoCount]
            aMemo[m.nMemoCount] = m.ix
            Replace All &lcFieldName With Chrtran(&lcFieldName,Chr(13)+Chr(10),Chr(10))
        Endif
        lcHeaders = m.lcHeaders + Iif(Empty(m.lcHeaders),'',',')+Proper(m.lcFieldName)
    Endfor
    tcHeaders = Evl(m.tcHeaders,m.lcHeaders)

    Use In (Juststem(m.lcTemp))
    Close Databases
    Set Database To

    loStream = Createobject('AdoDb.Stream')
    loConn = Createobject('ADODB.Connection')
    loRS = Createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
    loConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source="+m.lcTempDb
    loConn.Open()
    loRS = loConn.Execute("select * from "+m.lcTemp)
    loRS.Save( loStream )
    loRS.Close
    loConn.Close
    Erase (m.lcTemp)

    * Use first row for headers
    Local Array aHeader[1]

    loRS.Open( loStream )
    toRange.Offset(1,0).CopyFromRecordSet( loRS )  && Copy data starting from headerrow + 1

    Set Safety Off
    Delete Database (m.lcTempDb) Deletetables

    Select (m.lnSelect)

    For ix=1 To Iif( !Empty(m.tcHeaders), ;
            ALINES(aHeader, m.tcHeaders,1,','), ;
            loRS.Fields.Count )
        toRange.Offset(0,m.ix-1).Value = ;
            Iif( !Empty(m.tcHeaders), ;
            aHeader[m.ix], ;
            Proper(loRS.Fields(m.ix-1).Name) )
        toRange.Offset(0,m.ix-1).Font.Bold = .T.
    Endfor

    #Define xlJustify                                         -4130
    #Define xlTop                                             -4160
    * This part is cosmetic
    toRange.WorkSheet.Activate
    With toRange.WorkSheet.UsedRange
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop && set all to top
        For ix=1 To m.nMemoCount
            With .Columns(aMemo[m.ix])
                .ColumnWidth = m.tnPrefferredWidthForMemo && 80 chars width
                .WrapText = .T.
            Endwith
        Endfor
        .Columns.AutoFit
        .Rows.AutoFit
    Endwith
Endproc

* Return A, AA, BC etc noation for nth column
Function _GetChar
    Lparameters tnColumn && Convert tnvalue to Excel alpha notation
    If m.tnColumn = 0
        Return ""
    Endif
    If m.tnColumn <= 26
        Return Chr(Asc("A")-1+m.tnColumn)
    Else
        Return  _GetChar(Int(Iif(m.tnColumn % 26 = 0,m.tnColumn - 1, m.tnColumn) / 26)) + ;
            _GetChar((m.tnColumn-1)%26+1)
    Endif
Endfunc
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. My problem in Foxpro Automation is that in my report excel their is many formula incorporated that why it is very slow. Right now I figuring on how to copy a certain sheet to the Foxpro Automation working so that after i transfer the data in excel I will copy the sheets with formula to the working worksheets.

Comment: I think you didn't read the code. You could save the sheet(s) with formula as a template and add the new excel workbook based on that template, or you could write the formula for multiple cells at once. Or it only takes a single command to copy the sheets to a workbook from another.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for :-) I was trying with my knowledge of **Excel Automation** programming in **Visual FoxPro** but always got errors. My task was to create "n" Sheets from one big cursors which I want to parse regarding customer selection of attribute name from cursor to get also "n" Sheets. This sample is for 3 cursors and 3 Sheets and it is generic. But I need this for **"n" cursors** and **one attribute** which customer select **to distinct** and **get "n" Sheets** in one **Excel file**. So now I have **dynamic** procedure. I customized this code and solve my problem which I am trying to end for about 4 days. So again thank you for this code and off course I will not modify **VFP2Excel** procedure and wrote somewhere else my name. Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

There is no *native* VFP function to do this, BUT, there is an awesome open source project which has a class that will make this very easy:

**VFPx Workbook Xlsx** - See it here on Github: [XLSX Workbook for FoxPro](https://github.com/ggreen86/XLSX-Workbook-Class)

It has 3 magical functions that will do exactly what you asked for:

- CreateWorkbook()
- AddSheet()
- SaveTableToWorkbook()

(Repeat commands 2 and 3 above for each DBF/Sheet you want to create)

It is well documented with a 54-page PDF and code sample that explains everything you'll need to know.